# WPF Image.Source caching too aggressively

Tags: .net, wpf, caching

I have an instance of `System.Windows.Controls.Image`, and I set the contents programmatically as such:

```
Uri location = new Uri(uriString);
image.Source = new BitmapImage(location);
```

Sometimes I know that the image on the server has changed and I want to refresh it, but every time I repeat the above code I get the same image.

This seems to be a caching problem, but the two obvious solutions — `RequestCacheLevel` and `BitmapCacheOption` — seem to do nothing.  This code has the same result:

```
var cachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore)) {
    CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None
};
image.Source = new BitmapImage(location, cachePolicy);
// Still uses the cached version.
```

The only way I've found to force a refresh is to append a throwaway query string to the URI, which seems to work, but also is a complete hack:

```
Uri location = new Uri(uriString + "?nonsense=" + new Random().Next());
image.Source = new BitmapImage(location);
// This forces a refresh
```

How can I prevent these images from being cached, and/or force a refresh?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you need to set the CreateOptions on the BitmapImage to:

```
BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it!  Ugh, why are there so many caching options??

Comment: Saved me a lot of work finding it out myself. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if you set this option before BeginInit, it will be ignored .