# Image does not refresh in custom picture box

Tags: wpf, image, binding, bitmap

My custom picture box contains a scrollviewer and an image.
A dependecy property Image of type string is used to set the image.

```
public static DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Image", typeof(string), typeof(CustomPictureBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", new  PropertyChangedCallback(OnImageChanged)));


private static void OnImageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  CustomPictureBox cpb = (CustomPictureBox)d;
  if (e.Property == ImageProperty)
  {
    string newvalue = e.NewValue as string;
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(newvalue)))
    {
      var bmp = new BitmapImage();
      bmp.BeginInit();
      bmp.UriSource = new Uri(newvalue);
      bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
      bmp.EndInit();

      cpb.imgPicture.Source = bmp;
    }
    else
      cpb.imgPicture.Source = null;
  }
}
```

An image is acquired via frame grabber and stored to a given location with name "camera_image.tif". The Image property is set to this filename.
When I start a new image acquisition, I set the Image property via binding to null and the picture box updates to show no image. 
When the image acquisition is done, I set it to the "camera_image.tif" again. The problem is that the new image never shows up. Instead it is always the first acquired image that is displayed within the picture box. When I check the image file, it contains the new content.

How could I get the picture box to refresh the image?

Regards,

tabina

Comment: Have you removed your CacheOption? Get rid of that entire line; `bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`

Comment: If I did that, the second image acquisition would fail because it could not write its results to the file "camera_image.tif".

Comment: I want the user to be able to 1.) acquire an image, 2.) check if it is ok by displaying it to him, 3.) if ok: trigger a save to a different file location, 4.) if not ok: try again and acquire another image...

Comment: `OnLoad` closes the stream, `OnDemand`, the default behavior does not.

Comment: Apparently, I need to get the stream closed in order to get access to the file from somewhere else. Is there any way to tell the <Image> to release its cache? Or whatever else is neccessary to get the correct bitmap displayed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Reloading an image in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491383/reloading-an-image-in-wpf)
and here.
[WPF Image.Source caching too aggressively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137469/wpf-image-source-caching-too-aggressively)

```
bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

is the solution I was looking for!