# How to reload Image without changing the Source property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Assume I have an `Image` object which his `Source` property being initialized in the following way:

```
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
source.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
source.UriSource = new Uri("C:\\Temp\\tech\\window.jpg");
source.EndInit();
image.Source = source; // image object automatically initialized in the window construction.
```

As you can implicitly see, `window.jpg` is an image that permanently changed (get deleted and replaced with a new different image *with the same name*).

I have been using the above mentioned way to initialize the `Image` object `Source` property because I have found it at [Image does not refresh in custom picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518986/image-does-not-refresh-in-custom-picture-box) as a way to support the `Image` refreshing.

However, when deleting and replacing `window.jpg` while the program is running, the `Image` object still shows the image that was loaded when we initialized its `Source` property (cache).

It seems like the `Image` object ignores the `BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache` value and doesn't refresh the image when a new one replacing the previous that was deleted.

Any solution will be welcomed.

**EDIT**

I don't want to change the filename because I would need to redundantly find a random name that doesn't exist instead of just refreshing the image to load the same `Source` again.

I don't want to change the `Source` property value because of the fact that I don't change the filename.

The desired solution is to update the  `Image` object each time the image file changes. The image change controlled by me so there is no need to bind and wait for a change, instead, I would force an image refresh, if it possible.

Comment: Any solution to what? The only question I see is you asking to reload the `Image` without changing the value of the `Source` property. I don't think that's possible unless you use a writeable bitmap object (e.g. `WritableBitmap`, `RenderTargetBitmap`, etc.). But what's wrong with changing the `Source` property? And are you finding that when you change the `Source` property your image still does not get updated? Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise description of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, thank you for your replay. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is whenever I delete and create a new `window.jpg`, I set my `Image.Source` property with the `Image.Source` property *initialization mentioned in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

I would have an `Image` in XAML, and in the XAML, I would bind `Image.Source` to a property of type `ImageSource` on my viewmodel. I'd have a `FileSystemWatcher` update that `ImageSource` property when the .jpg on the disk changed, and I would raise `PropertyChanged` when that happened.

In XAML, you update UI control content/properties by using the `Binding` class to bind viewmodel properties to the control's dependency properties. The `Binding`s update the control in response to the raising of `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` events in your viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, it seems to work fine. Unfortunately, when reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes I'd prefer not to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was broken.